# Conexão ao banco sql em várias páginas php

Tags: php, sql, login

Estou criando um site em que várias páginas necessitam de conexão com o banco para realizar suas operações, por exemplo, eu fiz um sistema de login, assim que o usuário clica em 'login' abre um modal em bootstrap para digitar os dados. Eu criei a página "validaLogin.php" para fazer as verificações dos usuários e coloquei um `require "validalogin.php";` na navbar para chamar tal página. O que acontece é o seguinte: dentro desta página eu faço a conexão com o banco para realizar as operações, mas, quando eu abro uma página que também necessita de conexão com o banco, da o erro "conectaAoMySQL" já foi declarada e não pode ser redeclarada.

Resumindo: Duas páginas estão chamando a mesma função de conexão com o banco duas vezes e dá o erro, há alguma forma de realizar uma conexão só para todo o site?

```js
function conectaAoMySQL(){

  $conn = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
  
  if ($conn->connect_error)
    throw new Exception('Falha na conexão com o MySQL: ' . $conn->connect_error);

  return $conn;   
}
```

Comment: utilize require_once ou include_once dependendo da sua necessidade ao invés de require sozinho ou include sozinho

Comment: Pesquise sobre o design pattern lazy loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie um arquivo de conexão ao invés de uma função para isso, vou mostrar uma forma utilizando um exemplo funcional

conexao.php

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost"; /* pode deixar localhost */
    $username = "root"; /* nome do usuario do banco de dados */ 
    $password = "1521128"; /* senha do banco de dados caso exista senao deixa $password = "" */
    $dbname = "meubancodedados"; /* nome do seu banco de dados*/

    // Criando a conexão com o banco de dados
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Checando a conexão com o banco de dados
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
?>
```

e nos outros arquivos que você necessitar de conexão apenas coloque isso no inicio do arquivo

```
<?php include("conexao.php"); ?>
```

desta forma o arquivo inteiro irá ter conexão com o banco de dados podendo ter 100 linhas quanto 10.000 sem necessidade de ter que chamar a função várias vezes, e, pronto obterá conexão para todos arquivos necessário de uma forma simples

Comment: O erro de conexão saiu depois que tirei a função, porém agora o problema é o seguinte, a parte de login ta funcionando normalmente, porém quando vou submeter outro formulário em outra página, ele acusa dois "Notices" avisando que "login" e "senha" do formulário de login não estão definidos, os dados são armazenados normalmente no banco porém da esses notices, sabe como posso retirá-los?

Comment: Tente colocar um if(isset($_POST["login"]) && isset($_POST["senha"])){chamaFuncao} no local que faz a checagem do login, assim se essas variaveis existirem ele faz o login, caso contrário ele nem tenta.

Comment: abra uma nova pergunta e coloque o link dela abaixo do meu comentário, em um comentário seu. Ai iremos te ajudar, para não bagunçar este tópico que pode ser de ajuda para outros usuário também

Answer (score 0):

Sempre quando várias páginas vão executar requisições ou inclusões opte por "require_once" ou "include_once" pois eles evitam inclusões duplicadas em casos onde uma página acidentalmente tente chamar um arquivo 2 vezes.

Comment: Coloquei o include_once nas duas páginas, em apenas na pagina de validaLogin.php mas não resolveu.

Answer (score 0):

Segue código da página "validaLogin.php".

```
<?php
include("conexaoMysql.php");

session_start();

function filtraEntradaV($dado){
    $dado = trim($dado);
    $dado = stripslashes($dado);
    $dado = htmlspecialchars($dado);
    return $dado;
};  

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST'){
    $login = filtraEntradaV($_POST["login"]);
    $senha = filtraEntradaV($_POST["senha"]);


    $sql = "SELECT Login FROM usuario where Login = '$login' and Senha = '$senha' ";
    $resultado = $conn->query($sql);

    if($resultado->num_rows <= 0){
        echo "<script>alert('Dados incorretos')</script>";}
    else
        $_SESSION["login"] = $login;

}


?>
```

Segue código da outra página

```
include("conexaoMysql.php");

function filtraEntradaC($dado){
    $dado = trim($dado);
    $dado = stripslashes($dado);
    $dado = htmlspecialchars($dado);
    return $dado;
}   

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST'){
    $msgErro = '';
    $nome = $email = $motivo = $mensagem = "";


    $nome = filtraEntradaC($_POST["nome"]);
    $email = filtraEntradaC($_POST["email"]);
    $motivo = filtraEntradaC($_POST["motivo"]);
    $mensagem = filtraEntradaC($_POST["mensagem"]);

    try{


        $sql = "
            INSERT INTO clinicamedica.contato(Id, Nome, Email, Motivo, Mensagem)
            values (null, ? , ? , ? , ?);
        ";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $nome , $email , $motivo , $mensagem);

        if (! $stmt->execute())
            throw new Exception("Erro ao realizar o contato: " . $conn->error);


        $formProcSucesso = true;
        } catch (Exception $e){
            $msgErro = $e->getMessage();
        }
}
?>
```

Quando submeto o formulário desta outra página ele acusa que login e senha da página de validaLogin não estão definidos.

Comment: o nome do arquivo de conexão que você criou foi este mesmo ? conexaoMysql ?

Comment: Sim, já estava criado, eu apenas retirei a função dela e resolveu, porém está com o erro relatado em cima.

Comment: coloque a sessão antes do login, e coloque a sessão no segundo arquivo também  ficará => session_start(); include("conexaoMysql.php");

Comment: Ele submete os dois formulários: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ClinicaMedica\php\validalogin.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined index: login in C:\xampp\htdocs\ClinicaMedica\php\validalogin.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: senha in C:\xampp\htdocs\ClinicaMedica\php\validalogin.php on line 14

Comment: está indicando que uma sessão já havi sido iniciada, tente verificar senão tem duas chamas de session_start()

Comment: Sim, o problema está nessas variáveis, existe alguma forma de eu fazer essa verificação de login sem chamar a função na navbar? Pois o formulário precisa estar no modal

Comment: olha faz o seguinte, abra uma outra pergunta pois senão vai ficar 5 perguntas e respostas em um único tópico, e cite seus novos problemas, apague esta sua resposta, pois ela também é uma pergunta, e marca a  resposta que melhor te atendeu, lá como a melhor para os outros usuários virem que já tem uma solução e ninguém meio que perder tempo tentando solucionar este problema que já é resolvido. Ai você coloca o link da nova pergunta aqui e eu ajudo você novamente ok ?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254256/login-no-modal-do-bootstrap

Comment: não esqueca de remover esta "resposta agora, para não bagunçar este tópico, por favor