# Login no modal do bootstrap

Tags: php, sql, login

Criei um botão de login na navbar do site, quando o usuário clica abre um modal com o formulário de login. No arquivo php da navbar estou chamando o arquivo "validaLogin.php" para verificar os dados de usuário e armazenar numa variável de sessão, porém quando vou submeter um outro formulário em outra página, ele submete os dois formulários, por exemplo, na pagina de contato, tem um formulário, e ao clicar em enviar no form, ele submete nos dois, porém como na página não existe as variáveis do formulário de login dá o seguinte erro:

> "Notice: Undefined index: login in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ClinicaMedica\php\validalogin.php on line 13
>
> Notice: Undefined index: senha in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ClinicaMedica\php\validalogin.php on line 14"

validaLogin.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("conexaoMysql.php");

function filtraEntradaV($dado){
    $dado = trim($dado);
    $dado = stripslashes($dado);
    $dado = htmlspecialchars($dado);
    return $dado;
};  

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST'){
    $login = filtraEntradaV($_POST["login"]);
    $senha = filtraEntradaV($_POST["senha"]);


    $sql = "SELECT Login FROM clinicamedica.usuario where Login = '$login' and Senha = '$senha' ";
    $resultado = $conn->query($sql);

    if($resultado->num_rows <= 0){
        echo "<script>alert('Dados incorretos')</script>";}
    else
        $_SESSION["login"] = $login;

}


?>
```

página de contato:

```
<?php
include("conexaoMysql.php");

function filtraEntradaC($dado){
    $dado = trim($dado);
    $dado = stripslashes($dado);
    $dado = htmlspecialchars($dado);
    return $dado;
}   

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == 'POST'){
    $msgErro = '';
    $nome = $email = $motivo = $mensagem = "";


    $nome = filtraEntradaC($_POST["nome"]);
    $email = filtraEntradaC($_POST["email"]);
    $motivo = filtraEntradaC($_POST["motivo"]);
    $mensagem = filtraEntradaC($_POST["mensagem"]);

    try{


        $sql = "
            INSERT INTO clinicamedica.contato(Id, Nome, Email, Motivo, Mensagem)
            values (null, ? , ? , ? , ?);
        ";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $nome , $email , $motivo , $mensagem);

        if (! $stmt->execute())
            throw new Exception("Erro ao realizar o contato: " . $conn->error);


        $formProcSucesso = true;
        } catch (Exception $e){
            $msgErro = $e->getMessage();
        }
}
?>
```

Como posso resolver?

Comment: editei seu código acima, no arquivo validaLogin.php estava sem fechar o if, tente copiar e colar este arquivo editado no seu arquivo e verifique o que retorna, caso dê algum erro postei uma resposta para ajudá-lo

Comment: Eu alterei o action do form de action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); para action="php/cadastrocont.php" ai deu certo. Vlw!!